# When does "file content indexing" happen in Windows, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I see that in Windows 10, every drive, every folder, and every file has an option to "allow file content to be indexed", and they're **on** by default:

I don't need file-content indexing, and I don't want it to happen, so I'd like to know, when does it happen?

If I go to `Indexing options` in settings, I can see that I have removed indexing for almost everything, but I'm not sure if that's enough.

If I go to `Indexing options > Advanced > File types`, I can see content-indexing of many file types are enabled by default (e.g. `docx`). Does that mean the content-indexing of these file types will happen automatically? There are too many filetypes so it's impractical to turn them off one by one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Start and type "Services"

[image]

Then right-click Windows Search and click on Properties

[image]

Set Startup Type: "Disabled"
Then Stop Service.

Services can get triggered to restart if it's not running, stopped, or crashed.

Warning: Some services and software may rely on Windows Search.
For example, running a Media Server on your network depends on Windows Search. That's when you can cast movies to smart TVs using UPnP and Windows Media Player.

[image]

Edit:
As per the comment I tested searching in the start menu after disabling Windows Search Service.

Conclusion:

It doesn't affect searching settings and items in the start menu. But windows does warn you that Indexing is turned off.

[image]

Comment: Will this disable searching in Windows Settings and searching for items in Start Menu? These are the only 2 things I need to search.

Comment: @ZYinMD I updated the answer, and I tried it and it seems to work fine for searching for items in the start menu and settings.   
If my answer helped, I would appreciate marking it as an answer it sure would help.

Answer (score 0):

> When does "file content indexing" happen in Windows, and how can I
> prevent it?

I think you may have possibly misinterpreted what you saw.

**(A)** "Allowing files to have contents indexed" does not mean that will happens. It just means you can select file contents if you wish for appropriate files (.DOCX for example).

**(B)** File Properties (your last screen shot) does not include Contents unless the Index Properties and Contents has been selected. Mostly (EXE and like files) it is NOT selected. Again, only selected if you so select (except for some really obvious file types that Microsoft pre-fills).

**(C)** Your summary screen shot:  You have only selected Start Menu and so have very little indexed and that should allay your fears that something is happening that you are unaware of.

**(D)** In the locations screen (your summary screen) on my computer, I include Outlook, USERS, and a General Software folder I have. 170,000 items indexed. I know exactly why (proper selection of Content Properties and Locations).

So just go through your last screen (File Types) and ensure correct selection of Contents and then in the Location screen, select the locations you want. This comes with experience.

You can reduce (prevent) indexing by reducing locations and Contents to just a few (DOC, XLS, PDF), or even by having only your start menu.

Comment: If I remove most things from "the summary page", as shown in the screenshot, but leave indexing enabled in file types, (things like txt or docx are enabled by default), will those files be indexed or not? Too many file types are enabled by default, so it's hard for me to turn them off one by one.

Comment: Anything with content indexing by default will not use much resource on any disk.  Once indexing is complete, you won't even see it in CPU.  Do not index the location if you do not want to search that. Indexing in the large is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing uses a lot ressources and slow down the hard drives I/O (this is even far worse with mechanical disks) for little benefits.

To completely stop Windows' Indexer, you must use Windows' "Services" tool (aka services.msc) and completly disable the "Windows Search" service.

People have disabled Windows' Indexer for years":https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-windows-search-indexer/914286d5-9485-49a9-a3df-f9516c9970cd

Comment: I followed the steps in the link (stopped the "Windows Search" service) but as soon as I open the start menu, the service restarts.

Comment: @ZYinMD see answer below for stopping Windows Search service.